# How to translate C-i to F8

Tags: key-bindings, key-translation-map

I have tried the following:

```
(keyboard-translate ?\C-I (kbd "<f8>"))
(keyboard-translate ?\C-I [(f8)])
```

The representation of F8 key is wrong.

Comment: The way you use `keyboard-translate` you hit `?\C-I` and get `(kbd "<f8>")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyboard-translate` takes character arguments, and `(kbd "<f8>")` does not evaluate to a character.

Try this:

```el
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-i") (kbd "<f8>"))
```

but take note!  `C-i` is the same thing as `TAB`, so this also makes the TAB key act as F8.

In GUI frames you can use bindings for `<tab>` which is independent of `TAB`; but for cross-terminal compatibility anything binding the TAB key will normally use `TAB` and leave it to the default translation of `<tab>` => `TAB` to make GUI and text terminals behave the same way.  So if you *don't* want your TAB key to act as F8 you probably need to introduce a bunch of new bindings for `<tab>` (and then only use GUI frames).